# create accordian UI in sapui5

Tags: sapui5, jquery-ui-accordion

I have to create accordian UI in sapui5. How can I create accordion type list in sapui5? e.g.

```
<http://codepen.io/css-tricks/full/LufJE>

<http://jqueryui.com/accordion/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use Panel control in the following link.

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.PanelExpanded/preview

2. Try HTML5 Detail/Summary if it fits your needs (you can embed HTML in your XML views)
3. You can just use jQuery toggle function to toggle the Divs.

Answer (score 1):

This is an accordion solution, that interlocks the expanded state of multiple Panel controls and in addition makes the headers of these Panels clickable (which makes the accordion handling more intuitive).

Plunker demo:
https://embed.plnkr.co/TXXLm12UvlMKYm7biaWQ/

View:

```
<mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:f="sap.f" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" controllerName="demo.controller.Home" displayBlock="true" async="true">
  <Page id="homePage" title="Home">

    <List id="idList" items="{accordion>/accodata}">
      <items>
          <CustomListItem>
              <Panel expandable="true" expanded="{accordion>expanded}" expand="onPanelExpand">
                <headerToolbar>
                  <Toolbar active="true" press="onPanelToolbar">
                    <content>
                      <Text text="{accordion>title}" />
                    </content>
                  </Toolbar>
                </headerToolbar>
                <content>
                  <Text text="{accordion>content}" />
                </content>
              </Panel>
          </CustomListItem>
      </items>
    </List>

  </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Controller:

```
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("demo.controller.Home", {
    onInit: function() {

      var oMyModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
          accodata: [{
            expanded: false,
            title: 'Title A',
            content: 'Content AAA'
          }, {
            expanded: true,
            title: 'Title B (expanded on init)',
            content: 'Content BBB'
          }, {
            expanded: false,
            title: 'Title C',
            content: 'Content CCC'
          }, {
            expanded: false,
            title: 'Title D',
            content: 'Content DDD'
          }]
        }

      );
      this.getView().setModel(oMyModel, "accordion");

    },


    onPanelExpand: function(oEvent) {
      if (oEvent.getParameters().expand) {
        var oModel = this.getView().getModel("accordion");
        var aPath = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("accordion").getPath().split("/");
        var selectedIndex = +aPath[aPath.length - 1];
        var aAccordion = oModel.getProperty("/accodata");
        for (var i = 0; i < aAccordion.length; i++) {
          if (i !== selectedIndex) {
            aAccordion[i].expanded = false;
          }
        }
        oModel.updateBindings();
      }
    },

    onPanelToolbar: function(oEvent) {
      var oPanel = oEvent.getSource().getParent();
      oPanel.setExpanded(!oPanel.getExpanded());
    }

  });
});
```